# Internal Links to Pages in PHP?

Tags: pages, links

What is the best way of linking to WordPress pages with PHP? Considering that I move the page from a local server to a live server to another URL?

```
<a href="/wordpress/services" title="Read More" class="yellowButton">Read more</a>
```

How could you replace this code with PHP linking to the WordPress page.

```
/wordpress/services
```

Comment: I know it might seem like a silly question, But I would like to know what is the best solution for linking to pages, Do you link directly to a ID or a page name. I don't understand the WordPress Codex page. Could someone please give a PHP example of this.

Comment: What do you *know* about the page? Title? Page ID? Nothing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Page Permalink from $id

If you know the Page `$id`, use [`get_permalink()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink):

```
<?php $permalink = get_permalink( $id ); ?>
```

## Page Permalink from $slug

If you know the Page `$slug`, such as `/about` (including hierarchy, such as `/about/work`), use [`get_page_by_path()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_by_path) to determine the Page `$id`, then use `get_permalink()`.

```
<?php
$page_object = get_page_by_path( $slug );
$page_id = $page_object->ID;
$permalink = get_permalink( $page_id );
?>
```

## Page Permalink from $title

If you know the Page `$title`, such as "Some Random Page Name", use [`get_page_by_title()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_by_title), then use `get_permalink()`:

```
<?php
$page_object = get_page_by_title( $title );
$page_id = $page_object->ID;
$permalink = get_permalink( $page_id );
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Do you want to find them by name? If yes then you can

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url('/services'); ?>"> Services </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hardcode '/page-names' you can use **home_url('/wordpress/services')** function with esc_url() for sanitizing URLs - it will always get you full url of home page ( local or live )

```
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/wordpress/services' ) ); ?>"
 title="Read More" class="yellowButton">
 Read more
</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a shortcode to insert the domain name into the internal link and then just add the page url on the end e.g [domain_name]/page-name.

Add this code into your child themes function.php and it's ready to go!

```
//add shortcode that displays current site name
function domain_name(){
$currentDomain = "yoursite.com";
return $currentDomain;
}

add_shortcode('domain_name', 'domain_name');
```

I've tested this on multiple live sites and it appears to be working perfectly.

Hope this is what you're looking for!